# How can I check if a Point Node is free?

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm working on a simulation on Anylogic where there is a buffer for containers in a port.

I use Point Nodes to mark destinations for the containers, but how can I check if there is already a container (an agent) on that Point Node (on that position) ?

PS : don't mind my mistakes, english isn't my native language.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please provide us some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want us to help, as you didn't give us any information so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pre-build way as point nodes do not keep track of agents on top of them. You can have as many as you want.

So you have to do it manually and there are many ways. One suggestion:

create a collection of type LinkedHashMap with key=PointNode and value storing the agent currently at that node.

This way, you can keep track easily. (You might need to read up on LinkedHashMaps first, if you don't know them).

cheers